# How do you redirect from one directory to another and maintain the proper basepath?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect all /eula traffic to /tos

```
RewriteRule ^/eula/$ /tos [R=301,NC]
```

but this rule doesnt seem to work -- mostly because the basepath is being treated as the root when really theres another parent directory; what's happening with the above rule is >

```
/my/docs/eula -> /tos
```

which is not right, it should be doing this >

```
/my/docs/eula -> /my/docs/tos
```

How do I write the rule for this, without having to specify what the parent dir is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteRule ^(.*)/eula$ $1/tos [R=301,NC]`

Comment: i did just that! =/ and it didnt work which is why this is driving me crazy. What about /eula/ its a directory... dunno it looks like it's adding the back slash, so maybe the rule isnt being processed in the right order